If I have corrupt/missing blocks but good a chainstate, why do I need to re-download entire chain?
If I have corrupt or missing blocks but good a chainstate, why do I need to re-download entire chain? Why doesn't it just re-download the needed blocks?

Because nobody has implemented a feature to deal with this rare situation. There is nothing fundamentally hard about it; it just doesn't exist.

Actually, according to this, there is PR#10794 (or the more recent RPC command getblockfrompeer, #20295), which does somewhat what I'm looking for.
